# Iterator JsonObject and JsonArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

Below there is my json. I need get two strings in loop. How do it in one loop?
Any ideas? Thanks

This is my part of code:

```
JSONObject documentJSON = result.getJSONObject(SyncConsts.VALIDATION_ERRORS);

for(Iterator<String> iter = documentJSON.keys();iter.hasNext();) {
String key = iter.next();
}
```

Example:
**Quantity - Wrong value, input must be a number**

```
{"Errors":{"Quantity":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"},"Amount":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"},"Amount_name":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"},"Amount_name_first":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"}}}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you have tried? Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: Can you tag your question with the correct language? It will help getting the right people to see it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json = {"Errors":{"Quantity":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"},"Amount":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"},"Amount_name":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"},"Amount_name_first":{"wrongValue":"Wrong value, input must be a number"}}}
var k = {} ,j = 0;
for(i in json.Errors){
   k.j = (i + ' - ' + json['Errors'][i]['wrongValue']);
   j++;
}
```

now you have `k` variable for single loop

Comment: Can you do it also in Java?